# Paypal Sandbox IPN Problem

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn

Iam working with paypal payment with my project(in django) i have enabled IPN settings in paypal sandbox iam sending return url and notify url as parameters with "buy now" button.but i didn't get any IPN response. Iam using 192.168.1.10:xxxx IP address is there any problem with ip address?

Answer (score 3):

Addresses in the form 192.168.x.x are local only - they are only accessible within your local network. There's no way Paypal can post anything to that address. You will need to configure your router to forward inbound HTTP requests to your local machine, and use the external IP address of your router. Alternatively, deploy it to a staging environment with a real IP address.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completion i'll add the easiest free solution to this problem.
Install ruby and then [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/)

And then you can do:

```
./manage.py localhost:8000
localtunnel 8000
```

And you get an url for the world to visit your localhost.

Comment: commenting for people that might find that now. Ngrok is alternative to localtunnel